# Automatically fill a column based on some criteria from other columns

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this question.

I'm working on a worksheet which has 3 columns R, SF and DF where the performance percentages 
of each of these variables are recorded (R, SF, DF).

If the percentage is greater than 90, the variable is classified as Critical. If the percentage is greater than or equal to 80 and less than 90, the variable is classified as Attention. 
Finally, if the variable is greater than or equal to 60 and less than 80, the variable is classified as Trigger.

I would like to automatically fill another column by comparing the 3 percentages of each variable and taking the highest value. If the highest value is the variable R, for example, then the cell in this other column will be filled with R and its respective classification,
(C -Critical or A - Attention or T - Trigger).

Comment: Sounds like you don't really need VBA here.

Comment: You may be able to get away with just using the worksheet function `MAX`, and then applying the correct classification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Non-VBA Solution

**Consider two formulas:**

1. `=SWITCH(MATCH(MAX(B2:D2),B2:D2,0), 1, "R", 2, "SF", 3, "DF")`
2. `IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=90,"C",IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=80,"A",IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=60,"T","")))`

---

The first formula will provide you with the column index *(based on the input range)* that is associated with the `MAX` value. You can then use `SWITCH` to convert the index - in this instance, we convert to a string. The conversion is as follows:
 `Column Index:Output` = `1:R`, `2:SF`, `3:DF`

The second formula is nested `IF` statements which gets evaluated from left to right. Once your criteria is met, the rest of the formula will not be evaluated so you only need to check for `Greater Than` criteria rather checking for `In Between` as you explained.

---

If you want the output in one cell you can just combine the formulas with `&` as shown below. I have also shared a photo of the setup I used so you can relate the formula to the ranges

```
A2 = SWITCH(MATCH(MAX(B2:D2),B2:D2,0), 1, "R", 2, "SF", 3, "DF") & IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=90,"C",IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=80,"A",IF(MAX(B2:D2)>=60,"T","")))
```

[image]

Comment: The original question asked for **greater** than 90% rather than greater than or equal, and also I think that there is a typo - you are setting "T" for being greater than -60, rather than being greater than or equal to 60.

Comment: @Applecore thanks for catching the typo! I'm going to give OP the benefit of the doubt  and assume [s]he can convert the numbers to percentages if needed and that [s]he can also drop the `=` sign if needed.

Comment: It's an assumption I am ok with making :)

Comment: @urdearboy thank you very much, your answer was extremely helpful! The explanation was very clear and didactic.

Comment: @Applecore  I appreciate your help.